# Split line into words and put them in char array using strtok

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, strtok

I have this simple line parser into tokens function...
But something im missing.

```
int parse_line(char *line,char **words){

   int wordc=0;

   /* get the first token */
   char *word = strtok(line, " ");
   words[wordc]=(char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
   strcpy(words[wordc++],word );

   /* walk through other tokens */
    while( word != NULL ) {
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        words[wordc]=(char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(words[wordc++],word );
    }

    return wordc;
}
```

When i run it i get a segmentation fault!
I give as first argument char[256] line and as second of course a char** words but i have first malloc memory for that one. like that

```
  char **words = (char **)malloc(256 * sizeof(char *));
```

```
main:
.
.
.
char buffer[256];
char **words = (char **)malloc(256 * sizeof(char *));
.
.
.
n = read(stdin, buffer, 255);
if (n < 0){
   perror("ERROR");
   break;
}

parse_line(buffer,words);
```

When program executes parse_line it exits with segmentation fault

Found where the seg fault occures. And it's on that line here:

```
strcpy(words[wordc++],word );
```

And specifically on the first strcpy. Before it even reaches the while loop

Comment: the char * line is a string yes! Like a line with chars

Comment: xing, what do you mean exactly? 
What else i have to allocate?

Comment: Please, add to your question a simple `main()` in which you define an example line and you call the `parse_line()` function

Comment: xing, if i allocate memory for the exac size of the first word, then if the second is bigger i would have a problem.

Comment: and why is a problem to allocate a safe big number from the beginning??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while( word != NULL ) {
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
    words[wordc]=(char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(words[wordc++],word );
}
```

At the end of the line, `word` will always be set to `NULL` (as expected) and so `strcpy(words[wordc++],word )` will be undefined behavior (likely a crash).

You need to reorganize the loop so you never try to copy a NULL string.

@jxh suggests this solution which fixes the issue of `word` being `NULL` in either of your `strcpy`s.

```
/* get the first token */
char *word = strtok(line, " ");

while( word != NULL ) {
    words[wordc]=(char*)malloc(256*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(words[wordc++],word );
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

I'd do this (uses less memory)

```
/* get the first token */
char *word = strtok(line, " ");

while( word != NULL ) {
    words[wordc++] = strdup(word);
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

Comment: it didn't help i think.
I have put another if after the first strtok inside the while to test id word==NULL.
But nothing. again i got segmentation f

Comment: Use a debugger (or printfs) to pinpoint exactly where the issue is.

Comment: If you show an example of what the code should look like, the OP will more likely be able to validate your answer, and the more likely you will get a check mark.

Comment: Your advice applies to first call to `strtok` too.

Comment: @jxh - I specifically avoid putting in example code for questions that seem to be "homework level". Have to look again but your refactor is not how I would have done it ;-) edit: your edited refactor *IS* how I would have done it :-) :-)

Comment: I found where the seg fault occures.
it's on the first strcpy. Before the while. There it crashes!

Comment: So check: is `word` already NULL (same problem as identified here) - the sample code @jxh put in will fix the problem in both places.

Comment: @John3136 The result of the allocation should also be checked in real life code.

Comment: @jxh too true - another reason I avoid putting in samples for simple questions - it's hard to resist fixing all the issues ;-)

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors
4. displays the results to the user
5. fails to pass all allocated memory to `free()` so has lots of memory leaks

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// avoid 'magic' numbers in code
#define MAX_WORDS 256
#define MAX_LINE_LEN 256


int parse_line( char *line, char **words )
{
    int wordc=0;

    /* get the first token */
    char *token = strtok(line, " ");
    while( wordc < MAX_WORDS && token ) 
    {   
        words[wordc] = strdup( token );
        if( ! words[wordc] )
        {
            perror( "strdup failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, strdup successful

        wordc++;

        // get next token
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return wordc;
}



int main( void )
{
    char buffer[ MAX_LINE LENGTH ];

    // fix another problem with OPs code
    char **words = calloc( MAX_WORDS, sizeof( char* ) );
    if( ! words )
    {
        perror( "calloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, calloc successful

    // note: would be much better to use 'fgets()' rather than 'read()'
    ssize_t n = read( 0, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
    if (n <= 0)
    {
       perror("read failed");
       exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, read successful

    // note: 'read()' does not NUL terminate the data
    buffer[ n ] = '\0';   

    int count = parse_line( buffer, words );

    for( int i = 0; i < count; i++ )
    {   
        printf( "%s\n", words[i] );
    } 
}
```

here is a typical run of the program:

```
hello old friend  <-- user entered line
hello
old
friend
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answers are right ! BUT i had segF again BECAUSE OF READ!!!!!
i didn't notice that when i run the program it didn't stop for reading from the input at read !
Instead it was passing it. What i did is i changed read to fgets and it worked !!!
With also your changes!
Can someone explain to me this???? Why it doesn't stop at read function??

Comment: 'read()' blocks until some kind of terminator is entered or the max number of characters is read.  are you entering an extra `return` key?